# Use of receiveTimeout property in SimpleMessageListenerContainer

Tags: spring-amqp

I have a listener which listens to one queue, I want a listener in such a way that my listener need to consume one message after another message with delay of 1 min. I have seen receiveTimeout property for the listener container but i couldn't able to achieve the delay in message consumption. here is my listener container.

```
<!-- search message listener container -->
    <bean id="listenerContainer"        class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="queueNames">
            <array>
                <value>TEST_QUEUE</value>
            </array>
        </property>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListenerAdaptor" />
        <property name="acknowledgeMode" value="AUTO" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
        <property name="receiveTimeout" value="60000" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want with the listener container configuration; the `receiveTimeout` is simply how long the container waits for a message before looking to see if, say, the container has been stopped.

You could play some games with an intermediate queue with dead-lettering and time-to live, but that will be complicated.

It would probably be easier to use `RabbitTemplate.receive()` (or `receiveAndConvert()`) if you want to get messages on a schedule rather than being event-driven.

There is a [new plugin for RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/) which might help you.

Comment: As you have mentioned I think we have to go for scheduler rather than event driven. Thank you.